# struct of bitmaps

Tags: c#, .net, struct, bitmap

I have this struct definition:

```
public struct Icon {
  public Bitmap bitmap;
  public Bitmap g_bitmap;
  public int bitmap_ID;
  public int g_bitmap_ID;
} 

Icon current = new Icon();
```

then I tried to load a bitmap from file:

```
current.bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
//Create the texture
current.bitmap_ID = TexUtil.CreateTextureFromBitmap(current.bitmap);
current.g_bitmap = new Bitmap(current.bitmap)
```

and the same for the other variables, but `bitmap/g_bitmap` continue to have `null` value, `bitmap_ID/g_bitmap_ID` are at `0`.

Not so sure to have understood how a struct work (my previous experience was in C). Tried to read the MSDN documentation but nothing helps.

Comment: try to post all the code initializing current

Comment: What are you doing for the other variables?  I'm not sure what your question is, if you've assigned something to those variables you should have whatever you've assigned to them.

Comment: Are you maybe passing that struct to a method and load the bitmap therein? Note that structs are value types, so the struct passed to the method as a parameter will not be changed if the parameter is changed within the method, unless it is a `ref` parameter.

Comment: exactly that. I was answering because I just found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry everybody,
I'm really a stupid. Forget to pass the reference to my method...

```
private void Load_Icon(Icon icon, string path) {
  icon.bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
  icon.bitmap_ID = TexUtil.CreateTextureFromBitmap(icon.bitmap);
  icon.g_bitmap = new Bitmap(icon.bitmap);
}
```

forgotten to add a `ref` to the first parameter. In this way it works just locally on a copy of `icon`. This works:

```
private void Load_Icon(ref Icon icon, string path) [...]
```

Pardon!

Comment: A response that illustrates what you did, describes what behaved differently than expected and shows how you solved it would surely be more beneficial for future readers :-)

Comment: I actually don't think this is going to be useful to anyone, because people coming here will most likely have problems relating directly to icons, whereas this would be more useful with a general type. But the effort to reply with what the problem was is appreciated :)

Comment: It may be useful to note that while calling a structure member will generally cause `this` to be passed by `ref`, structure members other than constructors or property setters should generally avoid modifying `this` because in some contexts it may effectively be passed by value, causing any modifications made to it within the method to silently discarded.  The compiler will not allow `this` to be passed by value to a constructor or property setter (it shouldn't ever pass `this` by value in any context, but the proper passing convention--`const ref`--doesn't exist in .net).

Comment: If you need to alter a structure within a method other than a property setter, the proper way to do it is the way you have done in your `Load_Icon` method--passing it as an explicit `ref` parameter (btw, can your method be `static`?)